# converting list of terms as nodes for network graph in r

Tags: r

i want to build a term graph for short texts,

```
getwd()
d1<-"C:/Users/PGLAB/Documents/abc.txt"
d<-readLines(d1)
> d
    [1] "april paris lyrics"               "vacation april paris"            

    [3] "book disneyland hotel california" "watch harrypotter"
```

## tokenize the texts

```
dd<-as.list(tokenize_words(d))
>dd
   [[1]]
   [1] "april"  "paris"  "lyrics"

   [[2]]
   [1] "vacation" "april"    "paris"   

   [[3]]
   [1] "book"       "disneyland" "hotel"      "california"

   [[4]]
   [1] "watch"       "harrypotter"

dds<-as.list(dd[[1]])
   [[1]]
   [1] "april"

   [[2]]
   [1] "paris"

   [[3]]
   [1] "lyrics"
```

now i want to make each term("april","paris","lyrics") as nodes and edges for all nodes.
i tried with TermDocumentMatrix and adjacency matrix,but it doesn't work properly,suggestions are welcome

Comment: How should look your expected output?

Comment: Thanks@ANG, i need to generate a graph with terms (april as node1,paris as node2 and lyrics as node3) with edges connecting all the nodes,likewise the graph should be constructed for each short texts. help me with guidance..Thanks again